# Styling input checkboxes w/ prettyCheckable

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I am attempting to style checkboxes and radio buttons. I found a jquery plugin that does this. I can get this to work ONLY if I use the supplied .png -- if I create my own .png it breaks.

.

Here are my two jsfiddle examples -- only difference is the image URL in the CSS:

This one does work: http://jsfiddle.net/pf3JA/1/  (supplied png)

This one does not:  http://jsfiddle.net/pf3JA/2/  (png I created)

.

```
 .prettycheckbox>a,.prettyradio>a {
   /*  background: url('sprites-sfa68604977.png'); */ 
       background: url('prettyCheckable.png'); 
  }
```

.

Here is a link to the author's plugin: http://arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable/

The javascript plugin does not reference a png and the css is just regular css, not scss/sass etc.

Comment: the positions of the images within the sprite are defined in the CSS.  Your sprite is vertical instead of horizontal, but you didn't change any of the defined positions.  Of course it doesn't work!

Comment: On their one the images are laid out horizontally. On your one the images are laid out vertically. Did you change the CSS to account for this change?

Comment: Interesting. I wonder why the author supplied a png tiled vertically and a PSD for editing tiled vertically. Also the CSS is not moving the image at all so I this is still unresolved. I will update the png.

Comment: I understand what is going on now. Because I did not specify background-repeat: none; it actually DID slide the image but since everything is in a perfect grid it just slid the repeated image over -- appearing not to do anything. Thanks everyone.